# Get Specific Text in Bash Output

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to get the ip only from this output but idk how.Is it possible to limit the output to only what i want.

```
VPN Connection Setting Name                          |kap1
Destination VPN Server Host Name                     |159.89.199.192
Destination VPN Server Port Number                   |5252
Destination VPN Server Virtual Hub Name              |kap
Proxy Server Type                                    |Direct TCP/IP
```

Another problem. The ip have port. I only want the ip. Sorry for another question. I appreciate your help you all.

```
VPN Connection Setting Name |kap1
Status                      |Connected
VPN Server Hostname         |159.89.199.192:5252 (Direct TCP/IP Connection)
```

Comment: Could you copy paste the content of the image as well? Thank you

Comment: I have answered to your 2nd question

Comment: @1995, try to keep all questions in single post itself. Also add your efforts in your post too as we all are here to learn, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have an input file:

```
$ cat vpn_info 
Item                                  |Value
--------------------------------------+--------
VPN Connection                        |kap1
Destination VPN Server Host Name      |159.89.199.192
Destination VPN Server Port Number    |5252
...
...
```

Then you can use one of the following commands:

**AWK:**

```
awk -F '|' '/^Destination VPN Server Host Name/{print $2}' vpn_info                                                            
159.89.199.192
```

You define `|` as a field separator then you print the 2nd field of your input when the line starts with `Destination VPN Server Host Name`

**SED:**

```
sed -n 's/^Destination VPN Server Host Name *|//p' vpn_info 
159.89.199.192
```

You ask `sed` to replace `^Destination VPN Server Host Name *|` by nothing and when it works you print the result.

**2nd input:**

```
$ cat vpn_info 
Item                                  |Value
--------------------------------------+--------
VPN Connection                        |kap1
VPN Server Hostname                   |159.89.199.192:5252 (Direct TCP/IP Connection)
```

**AWK**

```
$ awk -F '[:|]' '/VPN Server Hostname/{print $2}' vpn_info                                                         
159.89.199.192
```

You can use this `awk` command where you specify 2 field separators `:` and `|` and you print the 2nd field when you reach the line that contains `VPN Server Hostname`

Comment: Thank you. It works! Can you please explain what the code do? I want to understand it so i can learn.

Comment: @1995: sure!!! I have added some explanations, is there a specific part that is not clear for you?

Comment: Probably all. Hahaha. I'm gonna read about awk and sed and try learning it. Thank you again. One last question, what if the ip is in between. Like this, string1 192.168.1.1 string2.

Comment: @1995, check my solution too once where I am checking that 2nd field with a regex about IP, though since your requirement is not that clear so you could let us know about complete question if these don't work for you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I updated my question. Hope you can help me.

Comment: @1995: I have added the answer to the ip with port ;-)

Comment: @1995, please check my EDIT solution now, also try to put all questions in a single time itself, let me know?

Comment: @Allan Thank you allan. Your code is less scary to understand. Hahaha. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the data you have shared is saved in a file.
File name : file.txt

```
$grep 'VPN Server Host Name' file.txt | awk -F '|' '{print $2}'
159.89.199.192
```

Comment: Nice but you can combine the `grep` and the `awk` in one command ;-)

Comment: @sonali, Welcome to SO, please always wrap your code in CODE TAGS a `{}` looking button for your posts, happy learning and keep sharing knowledge :)

Comment: Sure that is better :)

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT:*** Since OP is saying OP have a different kind of Input_file so adding solution accordingly now.

```
awk '/Hostname/ && match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

---

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk -F"|" '/Destination VPN Server Host Name/ && $2 ~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/{print $2}'  Input_file
```

OR

```
your_command | awk -F"|" '/Destination VPN Server Host Name/ && $2 ~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/\n/!s/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/\n&\n/;/^\S+[0-9]\n/P;D' file
```

Surround all ip addresses by newlines and only print those strings that match.

The first regexp looks for newlines. Newlines are what sed uses to delimit strings that it places in the pattern space (PS). Therefore, normally, newlines will never be found naturally in the PS unless they are introduced by the user by way of a substitution command. So the first command says "Unless there are already newlines in the pattern space i.e. the following substitution has already been made. Surround a string that looks like an IP address with newlines". An IP address is matched by one to three digits followed by a period, occurring three times followed by one to three digits. The next sed command, prints any such IP addresses and the last command removes the first line in the PS regardless of whether it was an IP address. If the PS is empty, following the `D` command, the next line is read in otherwise sed cycles through the commands again. So the overall effect of the commands is to list out all IP addresses on separate lines.

Comment: Thank you. I got what i wanted. I'm still new to bash so i don't even understand the code you wrote but thank you again.

Comment: @1995 regexp is a little language which allows you to validate, find and replace strings within strings. Spend a few minutes on them and they will save you hours later.

Comment: @potong I studied [this reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/sed.html), but the code above is still not quite clear to me. Could you please add step-by-step *human-readable* explanation?